# Wordpress Advanced Custom Field PDF Links Broken

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

We used the advanced custom fields plugin (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) on our Wordpress website to create fields for our custom Post Type (https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). The post type is called "publications", and displays all of our online PDF publications.

We have set the custom fields for the publications as so:

1st field - type of link (PDF, Online etc) (just a text field)
2nd field - Link to online version (link to PDF in media library)
3rd field - File upload (upload pdf file)

When a user views the publications archive page and select a publication, the archive is encoded to open the PDF link (3rd field) added to the publication

This has previously always worked (http://section27.org.za/section-27-publications/) and still is working for all older posts (this doesnt seem to be due to catch).

Though any new publications which are added, along with a PDF and link, now instead link to empty posts. (View SPOTLIGHT EDITION #4 - DECEMBER 2017 Copy at the bottom of the page - http://section27.org.za/section-27-publications/)

Please view the publications template which outputs the Publications:

```
            <section class="pubs">

            <?php
            $args = array (
            'post_type'              => 'publication', // your event post type slug
            'post_status'            => 'publish', // only show published events
            'orderby'                => 'title',
            'order'                  => 'ASC', // Show earlier events first
            'posts_per_page'         => -1,
            );

            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
            ?>

            <figure>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'publications' ); ?>
            <figcaption><?php the_title(); ?></figcaption>

            <?php if( have_rows('links') ): ?>

            <ul>

            <?php while( have_rows('links') ): the_row(); ?>

            <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url'); ?><?php
            the_sub_field('upload_pdf'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('type_of_link'); ?></a></li>               

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>

            <?php endif; ?>


            </figure>

            <?php 
            endforeach; 
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            </section>
```

Kind regards,
Joseph Hart

Comment: Why are you echoing out two fields in the href attribute? ('link_url' and 'upload_pdf')

Comment: I will change this to echo out a single link attribute, either one or the other and test. This code wasn't originally written by me so i cannot give you a definite to that, but i feel it may be a variable, so if the link_url is not added, it will refer to the "upload_pdf" variable for the link. 

This still does not cause the issue though. The issue is the custom fields are not being registered, so the single publishment post is just an empty post, and not a PDF link (the link either given by  link_url' or 'upload_pdf'. 

if this was outputting two variables, the URL would be broken.

Comment: Are the fields part of a larger collection of fields? If so, might there be a conflict with the field names? If they are not unique, saving them will fail.

Comment: @danjah thank you for your input. No these are actually the only custom fields on the site, and are all uniquely named. These were previously working and stopped without any update.